# Once jLine writes over one line to shell, we can't go back to original line

Tags: java, shell, command-prompt, jline

I've encountered the following problem with jLine. We open the command prompt (both linux and windows) and enter a stream of letters until it "spills" over to the next line. for example:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

We then try to delete the entered text, however the cursor will not go back up to the first line and it will remain on the start of the second line. This is a visual issue and not a logic one, since by printing out debug message and by pressing "enter" i can see that the buffer contains the string after all the deletions.

If anyone can help me figure out why this happens and how this can be resolved, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: The place to ask is on the [jLine SourceForge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dug a bit more into the [jLine SourceForge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/) and I found the when using jLine v2.7 the problem doesn't occur. However take into account that the API has change significantly so your implementation will have to be changed